# Replace last comma on string Lua

Tags: lua

I have this string

```
Apples, Oranges, Grapes
```

How can i replace **last comma** for **and**?

Havent learn enough of patterns but i've tried several ways such as

```
str:gsub(",$", "and", 1)
```

Isnt supposed that magic character **$**  reads string from end --> begin?

My problem becomes because im concatenating an array using **table.concat**

Comment: You cannot **"replace"** a character in Lua strings because they are immutable. That is, when created, they remain unchanged. You have to create another string with the last coma as **'and'**.

Comment: your pattern `",$"` doesn't work because it matches a comma at the end of the string. But your string doesn't end with a comma.

Comment: Ah, so `$` only reads last word of the string? So to speak @Piglet

Comment: no $ anchors the pattern to the end of the string. so it cannot match anywhere else but at the end of the string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your table:

```
local t = {"Apples", "Oranges", "Grapes"}
```

Method #1:
Concatenate the last item using "and":

```
local s = #t > 1 
          and table.concat(t, ", ", 1, #t-1).." and "..t[#t] 
          or  table.concat(t, ", ")
print(s)  --> Apples, Oranges and Grapes
```

Method #2:
Replace the last comma:

```
local s = table.concat(t, ", ")
s = s:gsub("(.*),", "%1 and")
print(s)  --> Apples, Oranges and Grapes
```

Answer (score 3):

```
local str = "Apples, Oranges, Grapes"
print(str:gsub(",(%s+%w+)$", " and%1"))
```